# How explicit is it advisable to be in App.config re: .NET runtime versions?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

A little knowledge can be a dangerous thing.

Now that I've had a "run in" with depending on various .NET runtimes being installed on a user's machine, I want to be as "safe" and code as defensively as possible.

However, if I add this to my App.config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v1.0.3705"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v1.1.4322"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v3.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v3.5"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
  </startup>
```

...is it tantamount to wearing suspenders, a belt, AND a cat suit?

(I'm targeting .NET 4 "standard")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but are you really using zero features of .NET 2.0+?

Comment: I don't know; do "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" and "<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>" not make sense together?

Comment: @ClayShannon I think that part makes sense, but if you are using features of the 2.0+ runtime, then you shouldn't say you're supporting 1.0

Answer (score 3):

Um... There is no 3.0 or 3.5. Just 2.0.xxx and then there is v4.0

Have a look at this msdn link. In particula the first graphic

[.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049%28v=vs.110%29)

Comment: Thats not the CLR version they are talking about. The chart shows that CLR 2 was used for 2, 3.0 and 3.5

Comment: Is the CLR really the runtime being referenced?